# Google Spreadsheet Chart options returning same width for all charts

Tags: charts, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-visualization

Using apps script I want to increase the width and height of all the charts (any type of charts may be - generic) in a sheet. I tried the below code but it always alerts 371 x 600, no matter that charts are resized/shrink ed etc

```
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var n = sheet.getCharts().length;

 for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {

     var chart = sheet.getCharts()[i];

     var th = chart.getOptions().get('height');
     var tw = chart.getOptions().get('width');

     showAlert(th + "  " + tw);

     chart = chart.modify()
         .setOption('width', th + 20) //set increased width
         .setOption('height', tw + 20) //set increased height
         .build();

     sheet.updateChart(chart);

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's working fine for me. (Note: the showAlert() function needs to be defined as described here: [GAS-showAlert](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#alert_dialogs))

The only problem I see is that you've mixed up width and height variables for the Options in your code. But it is working for me, no problem.

Comment: try resizing the charts with different sizes and at least add a minimum of 3 charts.

Comment: Don't declare the variables everytime inside the loop. example put `var th;` outside the loop. Only assign them inside the loop and check.

Comment: ok, tested it with various number of charts and you're right, there's something wrong happening there. With 1 chart sometimes it report the correct dimensions, sometimes not. Please report it to Google, there must be an internal error

Comment: Thank you, I had already reported Sujay - Star it @ https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=6653